# Connecting blobs with opencv 2.4 in java

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, computer-vision

I am using opencv 2.4 in java with eclipse. I am working on a project where I am trying to find text in an image. The image below is the point I am currently at after applying some techniques I read about were good for finding text. I want to give opencv the location of an image file and use it to get the coordinates of the bounding boxes around these 3 (or however many blobs get created from the previous steps) blobs individually. Then around all of them together. I am pretty sure opencv can do this in java but I am not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: Dialated Text Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Imgproc.findContours to find each blob
2. Iterate on each contour points and find the maxContour x coordinate maxContour y corrdinate minContour x and minContour y. The contour bouding box will be [minContour X,minContour Y] [maxContour X ,maxContour Y]
3. For each contour also keep track of maxAllContours X maxAllContours Y minAllContours X and minAllContours Y.
4. After iterating on all contours the total bounding box will be [maxAllContours X,maxAllContours Y] [maxAllContours X ,maxAllContours Y].

.